# How to change camera and mic source in agora unity?

Tags: agora.io, agora

i want to list camera and mic device that is available in a dropdown option, then using that list i want to change the video and audio source
until the listing process i already completed it by using DeviceInfo to list devices from IVideoDeviceManager and IAudioDeviceManager, it will return the device name and device id
but i dont know how to use it to change the stream source

Here is the code that i made to create the option list and it already worked

```
    public void PrepareCamSettings()
    {
        if (CamIdSelect == null || RtcEngine == null) return;

        CamIdSelect.ClearOptions();

        videoDeviceManager = RtcEngine.GetVideoDeviceManager();
        DeviceInfo[] deviceInfo = videoDeviceManager.EnumerateVideoDevices();
        CamIdSelect.AddOptions(deviceInfo.Select(w =>
                new Dropdown.OptionData(
                    string.Format("{0} | {1}", w.deviceName, w.deviceId)))
            .ToList());
    }
    public void PrepareMicSettings()
    {
        if (MicIdSelect == null || RtcEngine == null) return;

        MicIdSelect.ClearOptions();

        audioDeviceManager = RtcEngine.GetAudioDeviceManager();
        DeviceInfo[] deviceInfo = audioDeviceManager.EnumerateRecordingDevices();
        MicIdSelect.AddOptions(deviceInfo.Select(w =>
                new Dropdown.OptionData(
                    string.Format("{0} | {1}", w.deviceName, w.deviceId)))
            .ToList());
    }
```